# Laravel not retrieving values from database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to retrieve all column values. Following is the dashboard controller code, which runs index method by default

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\questions;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;

class Dashboard extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function fetchQuestions() {
        return questions::where('people_id','=',Auth::id())->pluck('question');
    }
    public function index(){
        $listQuestions=$this->fetchQuestions();
        return view('forms.question',compact('listQuestions'));
    }
}
```

View File

```
<ul>
@foreach ($listQuestions as $question)
    <li>{{ $question }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

It doesn't show any error or any result either

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
public function fetchQuestions() {
        return questions::where('people_id','=',\Auth::guard('yourguardname')->user()->id)->get()->pluck('people_id','question');
    }
```

Comment: @Jaskaran  : Sorry I had written first name , instead i rectified it \Auth::guard('yourguardname')->user()->id.

Answer (score 0):

Add ->all() after pluck

```
return questions::where('people_id','=',Auth::id())->pluck('question')->all();
```

Though you can do it in one method:

```
public function index(){
    $listQuestions=questions::where('people_id','=',Auth::id())->pluck('question')->all();
    return view('forms.question',['listQuestions'=>$listQuestions]);
}
```

Comment: what do you get when you dd($listQuestions)

Comment: i get this `array:1 [▼ 0 => "ok dere" ]` It works, but value doesn't pass or displays on the page

Comment: remove the compact and replace it with `['listQuestions'=>$listQuestions]`

Comment: its throwing error `Undefined variable: listQuestions`